# Syntax errors while trying to use a select statement as the condition for a while loop in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple loop I wrote to check if a random id is already in the table, else regenerate it:

```
random_id := dbms_random.value(1,100);
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANIMAL WHERE ANIMAL_ID = random_id) <> 0 
LOOP
    random_id := dbms_random.value(1,100);
END LOOP;
```

Running the code above gives the error:

```
Error(40,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat
```

and

```
Error(40,67): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem    <an exponent (**)> and or group having intersect minus order    start union where connect || multiset
```

As far as I can tell, no error in the editor.

Comment: Note that your loop will get slower and slower as more IDs are filled in; the odds of a match are X/100 where X is the number of IDs without rows. Once all are filled in the odds are 0/100 and it will never terminate.

Comment: First, note that `dbms_random.value` produces fractional values (in general); you need to `ROUND` or `TRUNC` the value, most likely, if you want to compare it to an `id`. (Assuming `id` is integer, the probability that a non-rounded random value will equal an `id` is **zero**.) Other than that, your code breaks because a `select` statement is a SQL statement, and that's different from PL/SQL. In PL/SQL, a `select` statement must select **into** something (a variable). But that is not the best approach; that way, you switch between PL/SQL and SQL (and back) for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Bohemian Still doesn't run but now I get a different error

Comment: @mathguy So within a PL/SQL block I have to insert it into some variable?

Comment: Not "insert" into some variable, but "select" into some variable. Or, as in the solution I proposed, create a single PL/SQL collection, execute a single `select` statement against the table, and **bulk collect** all the id's "into" that collection in a single pass. Then use that collection, rather than the table, for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach is to collect all the id's into a PL/SQL collection, so that you only make one context switch from PL/SQL to SQL (and back). Something like this; note that I use `empno` from table `emp` in schema `scott` for testing, since I don't have your table. The employee numbers are all between 7350 and 7950; I will pretend that I am looking for a number in that range that is not already assigned to an existing employee. (Similar to your attempt, if I got it right.)

The code begins by defining a local collection type, as a table of numbers (to hold the id's), and an instance of this local collection type. Then a single `select` using the `bulk collect into` clause collects the existing id's (employee numbers) into this collection instance, so the rest of the code is pure PL/SQL.

Also, please pay attention to what I told you in a comment: without rounding or truncating, `dbms_random.value()` produces non-integers in general, and that is very unlikely to be what you intended.

```
declare
  type id_list_t is table of number;
  id_list id_list_t;
  random_id number;
begin
  select empno bulk collect into id_list from scott.emp;
  random_id := round(dbms_random.value(7350, 7950));
  while random_id member of id_list loop
    random_id := round(dbms_random.value(7350, 7950));
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(random_id);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm aware of the non-integers, just that random_id is a NUMBER(6) so it's casted when passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The `Boolean expression`  referred to in [the documentation for WHILE loops](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/WHILE-LOOP-statement.html) cannot use an implicit cursor to retrieve and compare an anonymous value. This is true throughout PL/SQL syntax, not just for WHILE loops. For example, you cannot declare

```
tablesExist boolean := (select count(*) from user_tables) > 0;
```

A PL/SQL Boolean expression has to use PL/SQL variables, constants, literals, functions etc.

```
tablesExist boolean := tableCount > 0;
```

Implicit cursors can only be used in cursor FOR loops and `select into` constructions.